# Given $∃y.∀x.p(x,y)$, use the Fitch system to prove $∀x.∃y.p(x,y)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Given $\exists y. \forall x. p(x,y)$, use Fitch-style natural deduction system to prove $\forall x.\exists y.p(x,y)$.

I know this question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231508/288417), but based on that answer I'm not able to move forward from step 3 below. I'm using [Stanford's platform](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) as a proof assistant by the way, maybe that's the issue.
Any help is very much appreciated.

```
1.  EY:AX:p(X,Y)     Premise
2.  AX:p(X,Y).       Assumption
3.  p(X,Y).          Universal Elimination: 2
```

Comment: Yeah, different systems may have different formalizations, even if the rules are called the same.  Do you have a link to that platform you are using?

Comment: Now use Existential Introduction followed by Universal Introduction.

Comment: +Bram28, here's the link: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/coursera/exercise.php?exercise=exercise_08_06

Comment: Hi Mauro, nothing happens when I try to use EI

Comment: @Luen  The link doesn't work for me .. I assume I would need to be a student in this course ...

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is this [Stanford's platform](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess Stanford's platform you use is [this one](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) (in my opinion, not the best proof assistant in Fitch-style natural deduction).

In such a system, the elimination rule for the existential quantifier is a little unusual, since it uses Skolem terms (see [here](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/section.php?section=section_08_03) for an explanation), so there is no need for a further assumption.

The correct formalization of a proof of $\forall x \exists y \, p(x,y)$ from $\exists y \forall x \, p(x,y)$ in Stanford's platform is the following:
[image]

By the way, your approach is essentially correct if you use a more standard Fitch-style natural deduction system, such as the one implemented by [this proof assistant](https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) (which, in my opinion, is very intuitive to use). As @Bram28 said in his comment (and this is the reason why, in my opinion, your question is not a duplicate of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231508/288417)),

> different systems may have different formalizations, even if the rules are called the same.

In such a "more standard" Fitch-style system, the correct formalization of a proof of $\forall x \exists y \, p(x,y)$ from $\exists y \forall x \, p(x,y)$ is essentially the continuation of your attempt:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall \, Elim}: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall \, Intro}: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists \, Elim}: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists \, Intro}: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=Intro}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=Elim} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg Elim} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg Intro} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \exists y \forall x \,P(x,y)}{
 \fitch{2.\, \forall x \, P(x,b)}{
 3.\, P(a,b)  \Ae{2}
 4.\, \exists y \, P(a,y) \Ei{3}
    5.\, \forall x \exists y \, P(x,y) \Ai{4}
}\\
6.\, \forall x \exists y \, P(x,y)  \Ee{1, 2{-}5}
}
$

Comment: +Taroccoesbrocco amazing, thank you so much! Yes I've been told before that unfortunately Stanford's proof assistant is a little tricky.

Comment: Also thank you for such a detailed explanation, it really helped me understand the exercise and how to solve it.

Comment: @F.Zer - Yes, of course. Thank you. I fixed the typo.